# phpMyAdmin mySQL database not seem to be recognised in my code?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I'm having trouble getting my PHP code to actually do anything to register new users with a mySQl database I've set up using phpMyAdmin.

I've tried a number of ways of going about it, and feel that I understand what the code is trying to do quite confidently, but when I test it, I get no errors (or success messages).

The action on the button is performed (as it would be without PHP at all) and no new entry is inserted into my table 'tbl_users' in my database called 'cmeteventmanagement'.

To note, I am using wampserver, and the project is for educational purposes.

```
<!-- PHP to use form inputs with database -->
<?php

    // Define variables and set to empty values
    $firstname = "";
    $lastname = "";
    $email = "";
    $telno = "";
    $gender = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";

    // Declare variables to hold error messages for each field.
    $firstnameError = "";
    $lastnameError = "";
    $emailError = "";
    $telnoError = "";
    $genderError = "";
    $usernameError = "";
    $passwordError = "";
    $foundErrors = false;

    // If the form has been submitted, AND the method is POST
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // FIRST NAME
        $firstname = clearUserInputs($_POST["firstname"]);

        // LAST NAME
        $lastname = clearUserInputs($_POST["lastname"]);

        // EMAIL
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $emailError = "Email is required";
            $foundErrors = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $email = clearUserInputs($_POST["email"]);
        }

        // TELEPHONE NUMBER
        $telno = clearUserInputs($_POST["telno"]);

        // GENDER
        $gender = clearUserInputs($_POST["gender"]);

        if(empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            $usernameError = "Username is required";
            $foundErrors = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $username = clearUserInputs($_POST["username"]);
        }

        if(empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $passwordError = "Password is required";
            $foundErrors = true;
        }   
        else
        {
            $password = clearUserInputs($_POST["password"]);
        }

        // If no errors were found
        if($foundErrors == false)
        {
            // Declare variables for database and server connection
            $serv_name = "localhost";
            $db_user = "root";
            $db_pass = "";
            $db_name = "cmeteventmanagement";

            // Save form data to the MySQL database
            try
            {
                $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$serv_name; dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
                $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                echo "Connected successfully to Server and Database <br>";
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo "Connection to Server and Database failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            // Prepare SQL statements to insert data
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (firstname, lastname, email, telno, gender, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$firstname, $lastname, $email, $telno, $gender, $username, $password]);
            echo "New user registered successfully";
        }
    }

    // function to clear userinputs
    function clearUserInputs($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

?>

<!-- Start of HTML elements -->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header Links -->
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>

    <!-- Page Title -->
    <h1>Register</h1>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <!-- <form method="POST" action="events.html" autocomplete="off"> -->
    <form method="POST" action="login.php" autocomplete="off">
        First Name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="20">
            <br><br>
        Last Name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="20">
            <br><br>
        Email:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50">
            <br><br>
        Tel Number:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="telno" maxlength="15">
            <br><br>
        Gemder:
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
            <br><br>
        Desired Username:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="25">
            <br><br>
        Desired Password:
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" minlength="8" maxlength="15">
            <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the method (POST or GET) of HTML form on the client-side?

Comment: @Dashzeveg Hi and yes, method="POST", and action="login.php" because once the user registers, they will verify by logging in with that account. Anyway I did attempt to edit this post numerous times because the PHP and HTML tags confused everything, but it seems the last edit I thought worked, didn't even go through. I'll include the HTML now.

Comment: I think you should put `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in your action.  `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

Comment: @sauhardnc OK so this ultimately got my database to finally be recognised, as now I have some errors (better that then nothing haha!).

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\wamp64\www\CMETEventManagement\Register.php on line 93

Comment: @Master_Templar Basically what that means is that the no. of parameters and no. of values provided don't match, try this--  `$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (firstname, lastname, email, telno, gender, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";`

Comment: Side note: you can simply omit the whole `action` attribute from the `form` tag when you want to submit to the same script. The default action is submitting to self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have left the one question mark of parameters. So you need to add `?` into the `VALUES` section because you want to pass 7 parameters but there are 6 question marks.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (firstname, lastname, email, telno, gender, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: SOLVED

Not only were the number of parameters unmatched, but the order was incorrect as well.
Quickly resolved this issue thanks to everyone's help, with these two lines being changed:

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (user_username, user_password, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_gender, user_emailaddress, user_telnumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">